# Google Directions API - adding a via waypoint results in an error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-directions-api

I'm trying to an ETA from point A to C with a waypoint in-between, B.

This is the call I'm making to Google

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=true&mode=driving&origin=37.757946%2C-122.4048&destination=37.757954%2C-122.426349&waypoints=via%3A37.746560%2C-122.408328

it gives ZERO_RESULTS back which indicates no route could be found.

I added the waypoint with "via:" in front of it which doesn't add an additional leg to the route. However when I remove the "via:" the result is as expected.

These points are typical places in San Francisco so there definitely should be a route between them. If I use different lat/longs then it fixes it. But this error happens with more than just a few specific points.

Any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Remove via from your url
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=true&mode=driving&origin=37.757946%2C-122.4048&destination=37.757954%2C-122.426349&waypoints=37.746560%2C-122.408328

the URL above is correct now

Comment: I mentioned that in the question, I know it works without the Via but that adds an additional leg.